# Move Ubuntu 11.10 to primary partition?

Tags: 11.10

I would like to move Ubuntu 11.10 from `/dev/sda2` to `/dev/sda1` (hd0,0) without loss of updates, data, etc., and update grub.

If Ubuntu is backed up, a new install to a clean ext4 partition on sda1, including a new grub install (normal), THEN, restore [Home] from backup.

Is that going to preserve all my Ubuntu updates?
Must I backup the current install completely?

Thank you for any assistance in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the partition with a number of tools from dd to gparted. I would move it from a live CD.

Once you move the partition you need to do two things

### update-grub

First mount your new root partition.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Prepare the chroot

```
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
```

I personally would update and re-install grub

```
sudo chroot /mnt
update-grub
grub-install /dev/sda
```

### update fstab

While still in the chroot, edit `/etc/fstab` , make sure your root partition points to /dev/sda1

You can use "/dev/sda1" or UUID, to list your partitions by UUID use blkid

```
# If needed
blkid

nano /etc/fstab
```

Make sure your root entry looks something like

```
# / moved to /dev/sda1
UUID=xxxx-yyy-zzz  /  ext4  errors=remount-ro  0  1
```

Or

```
# / moved to /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1  /  ext4  errors=remount-ro  0  1
```

### Reboot

Reboot your computer and all should be well.

All the assumes you do not have a separate /boot partition. If you do, when configuring the chroot, mount your boot partition at `/mnt/boot`